# How to get current hash route in single page website

Tags: reactjs

I have a single-page web portfolio in which I have a navbar like the following code:

```
const Nav = ({ isToggled, onToggle }) => {
  const [activeNav, setActiveNav] = useState('#')
  return (
    <nav>
      <a
        href='/#'
        onClick={() => setActiveNav('#')}
        className={activeNav === '#' ? 'active' : ''}
      >
        <AiOutlineHome />
      </a>
      <a
        href='#about'
        onClick={() => setActiveNav('#about')}
        className={activeNav === '#about' ? 'active' : ''}
      >
        <AiOutlineUser />
...
   </nav>
   )
}
```

I have hyperlink tags to navigate through the website. However, I would like to update the active nav icon according to the current place the user is in. I found something called useLocation() from react-router-dom, but I currently do not use this package. Is it necessary? What should I do to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) package. I just switched my `a` tags for `Link` from react-scroll.
This:

```
      <a
        href='/#'
        onClick={() => setActiveNav('#')}
        className={activeNav === '#' ? 'active' : ''}
      >
        <AiOutlineHome />
      </a>
```

For this:

```
      <Link
        activeClass='active'
        to={'header'}
        spy={true}
        duration={500}
        offset={-100}
      >
        <AiOutlineHome />
      </Link>
```

In App.jsx, wrapped each component in `Element` from react-scroll (e.g. `<Element name={'portfolio'}><About /></Element>`).

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution I could think of would be combining the use ScrollTrigger plugin from [GSAP](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger) and React `useEffect`, they have really great documentations on their site! But this is the most basic example, say if you just want the nav link to show an active state if the section enters the viewport

```
useEffect(() => {
  gsap.to(".nav-link-className", {
    scrollTrigger: "#id", 
    // active state styling here
  });
})
```

EDIT:
Since I do not use GSAP myself that often, there may be a much better way of going about this within GSAP, but here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-robinson-r7xfm0?file=/src/App.js) on CodeSandBox, this should at least get you started. **Note** that one limitation (or at least my own limitation due to lack of knowledge with GSAP) is that I would have to hard code the animation when the trigger element leaves the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have never used GSAP. Could you provide a minimal example? As you can see from my example, I only need a setActiveNav inside useEffect which should enable me to update the styling (which is all I want). I just need a way to trigger the effect. How can I do it with GSAP?

Comment: Checkout the example I added in my answer for you! should get you started at least